# If I plan to run a python script that uses pyautogui can it do multiple computers at once or only one?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, user-interface, automation, cloud

Like if the script I uploaded to AWS has

pyautogui.moveTo(0,0)

Can it move the mouse of multiple computers at the same time or no?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a little more detail about what you are trying to achieve? It feels to me (I'm am only passingly familiar with AWS) that there are some contradictory terms. (AWS allows hosting of webpages, using python to move the cursor will affect only the server, not anyone who visits the webpage... the user would have to download the python script and run it for pyautogui to do anything?)

Comment: Im trying to make a bot that will be able to interact with websites from the server when I need it to. My computer isn't very fast so I thought uploading the script to a server would make it faster but wanted to know about pyautogui modules and how does it interact from server to target website. Sorry for the vagueness I'm obviously new to all this and thanks for the reply I appreciate it!

Comment: Don't worry about being new! Are you looking for something particular on the webpage? (like an image or text) Are you testing for some predefined behaviour? Or something else? I'm asking because this will determine how I or anyone else might answer. So yes, you could use the server to interact with webpages on your behalf. How does that relate to multiple computers? Can I ask you to update your question to state what you are trying to achieve, and something about what the expected output/effect is?

Comment: So I want to create a bot to buy clothes online and wanted to know if AWS has an option where I can do the task of adding the item to my cart and buying it on multiple accounts at once instead of one by one. So is it possible to have it go to Macys.com upload to my cart and purchase it using different computers that are using different Macy's account working in sync instead of buying one at a time. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author of PyAutoGUI. PyAutoGUI can only run on your single, local machine. It can't run on AWS or other "headless" setups. This might be added as a feature in the future, but it currently isn't on the roadmap. PyAutoGUI relies on having a GUI to interact with.

Comment: Oh ok thank you so much for answering I really appreciate it. I just wanted to say great work on the module really love it and ask one last question. Again apologies if this is a silly question since I'm new to alot of this but would it work with a proxy or no? Like can I use it on my computer to show the proxy what to click and what not to click or are proxies "headless" setups?