# How can I run a pyautogui bot on a server?

Tags: python, automation, bots, ui-automation, pyautogui

I made a pyautogui bot that logs into my social media accounts and likes the first post on my homepage(just testing and learning automation) but it uses my PC's mouse and keyboard; I wanted to know if it was possible to run it on a server (I don't have any knowledge on servers, but I understand that you can own one and have bots run on it), so that my pc stays available.

Any help is more than appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyAutoGui, But you can use virtualbox to install server or can use AWS EC2 service to create servers in few minutes (You can use one EC2 instance free of cost for a year know more here https://aws.amazon.com/free/)

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I have installed VirtualBox and it actually seems like I solved the problem since when I run the code on the machine it uses its own mouse and keyboard and I can keep using my pc. Still, I'll definitely give a look at servers and how they work. Thanks again

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The creator of the pyautogui package commented on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51411719/12750722). Apparently, pyautogui can't be used on servers like AWS or other "headless" setups.